# PHP Standard Deviation. Array_map function not found inside class function

Tags: php, callback, standard-deviation, array-map

I'm trying to perform a Standard Deviation with PHP.

I used this function I founded [there](http://php.net/stats_standard_deviation) because the stats_standard_deviation [doesn't seem to be reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12800458/1549310)

```
    <?php 
    class TestController extends \BaseController {

         function MyFunction() {
             $array = array('1','2','3','4');
             function sd_square($x, $mean) { return pow($x - $mean,2); } 

             function sd($array) { 
                      return sqrt(array_sum(array_map("sd_square", $array, array_fill(0,count($array), (array_sum($array) / count($array)) ) ) ) / (count($array)) ); 
             } 
    } return sd($array)
} ?>
```

The problem is that it returns me `array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'sd_square' not found or invalid function name` when I try to use it.

Looking at some post here I tried to change `"sd_square"` for `"self::sd_square"` or `array($this, "sq_square")`.

Comment: Please provide the full context. Is this in a class? Both in the same?

Comment: There does not seem to be any issue in your code. Are these functions residing inside any class. Can you post the full code.

Comment: The statistics extension is not bundled with PHP by default. You have installed it haven't you? http://www.php.net/manual/en/stats.installation.php

Comment: @vascowhite. I'm not using the bundle

Comment: @kingkero I made the edit

Comment: @Sabari I made the edit

Comment: You're in a class, so `sd_square()` is actually `TestController::sd_square()` and you must therefore use it as a callback like:  `array_map(array('TestController', 'sd_square'), ....)`   More examples are in the [PHP docs on callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)

Comment: @Michael - but is it? `sd_square` is inside `MyFunction` as well. I don't think `TestController::sd_square()` is right

Comment: @jon_darkstar Indeed. I didn't notice that due to bad indentation.

Comment: @Wistar How are you calling this function from outside the class? How do you pass $array to sd. It should work fine. Shows no error for me. Since your functions are inside MyFunction it can be accessed in that scope.

Comment: Yes - that tripped me up too.

Comment: @jon_darkstar Almost looks like transliterated JavaScript than PHP.

Comment: Did you try `array($this, "sd_square")`? You wrote you've tried `array($this, "sq_square")`!?

Comment: @Michael Hah yes it kind of does. Try adding `()` at the end maybe? =P

Comment: @l-x Yes I'v tried `array($this, "sd_square")` and it returns me "undefined variable this"

Comment: @Sabari I'm calling it from inside `MyFunction`

Comment: Try array('TestController', 'sd_square')

Comment: @Wistar return sd($array) is inside function sd () {} is that a typo ?? it should be outside that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of sidesteps the issue (and you should address it), but `sq_square` is small enough you may want to consider simply inlining

Change:

```
return sqrt(array_sum(array_map("sd_square", $array, array_fill(0,count($array), (array_sum($array) / count($array)) ) ) ) / (count($array)) );
```

To:

```
return sqrt(array_sum(array_map(function ($x, $mean) { return pow($x - $mean,2); }, $array, array_fill(0,count($array), (array_sum($array) / count($array)) ) ) ) / (count($array)) );
```

Or:

```
$sd_square = function ($x, $mean) { return pow($x - $mean,2); };
return sqrt(array_sum(array_map($sd_square, $array, array_fill(0,count($array), (array_sum($array) / count($array)) ) ) ) / (count($array)) );
```

Comment: This is NOT to say you shouldn't figure out the scope problems going on, but this is the kind of use case where I like anonymous functions (you can also consider assigning to a variable right beforehand like `$f = function ($x, $mean) { return pow($x - $mean,2); }`, this line is pretty damn long already)

Comment: I guess that my class issue comes from the framework I'm using. I'll figure that out with the documentation. For now, the anonymous function will do the job. Thanks.

Comment: Glad this works for you, but I really don't think the framework is the reason for your issue. I'd suggest you reorganize/refactor it all, and really look into the scope issues, when you have the time. They are likely to come up again.

Comment: @jon_darkstar, your formulas should end by `/ (count($array)-1) );` not `/ (count($array)) );`. Note the `-1`! (square root of sum of squares devided by N-1). See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stats-standard-deviation.php#97369